# How to take up multiple rows in skel.js HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

**Question explained:**

Unfortunately I can not find much documentation on skel.js except from the actual site. My goal is make a site such as `http://etchapps.com` and in the middles they have a square (metro style in a way) that takes up multiple rows. I doubt they are using skel.js to accomplish this but that is most lightweight option and satisfies my OCD. My website is `http://mellowdev.com` and I already have the base for the site. I was just curious on how I could add tiles in a way of different height and width, not just width. I hope I explained this properly, as it really is a simple question.

**What I am looking for in an answer:**

Any exampled code would be the best for solution to my question, however resources and links to some tutorials or other sites that could help with skel.js or maybe a better grid system such as Foundation 4.  I have tried Twitter Bootstrap & Foundation 4 but both seems very bulky for what I needed. If what I am trying to achieve is easier or possibly only available in a different grid system, I would love to know that as well. Thank you for taking the time to read all of this and I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid systems should be dynamic heights in general.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="3u">
     <div class="row flush">
      <div class="12u"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="row flush">
      <div class="12u"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="6u full-height"></div>
  <div class="3u">
     <div class="row flush">
      <div class="12u"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="row flush">
      <div class="12u"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you should set the .full-height class an 100% height.